# how to deploy the different spring boot micro service in tomcat with eureka, zuul server too?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I have bellow spring boot microservice. these jar files 
  1, test-service -port no-8100
    2, test-service -port no-8101
   3, Zuul server, config server also there.

how to deploy the above service in tomcat server

Answer (score 0):

Modify your maven or gradle build to produce a Package as a war.

Comment: But Tomcat is running a different port number. microservice are running different port .how it is possible ?

Comment: They would use different ports when running in the same VM. What you are attempting is not currently a best practice at all but is very doable.  HERE IS A LINK THAT IS A TUTORIAL FOR HOW TO DO IT. https://dzone.com/articles/run-configure-multiple-instance-in-a-single-tomcat

Comment: You can also combine all into same same application. Is there a reason you just want to use one tomcat server for deployment? Is it for a development environment?

Comment: Thanks for response Edwin.let we assume, I have 20+ spring boot micro service applications. if we create an instance per service it is more cost right

Comment: those are running multiple dynamic port numbers too

Comment: If you have a need for 20 micro services you are now in need of deploying each in their own instance. You don't want a failure of one micro service or bad deployment to bring down the rest of the services. That would defeat purpose of going the micro-service route. Grouping multiple spring boot services on one tomcat might be ok for a development server only and/or your testing setup. In my experience 4 instances on one VPS is already a lot and requires more memory.